# Cannot change Okular's default page size under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: printing, kde, okular

After installing Ubuntu 18.04, Okular always defaults to "A4" as the page size, even if I have set the page size to "letter" everywhere.

For example, even if in Okular's printer dialog I click "Properties" and set "Page size" to "letter," once I go back to that dialog it says "A4" again.

My system settings are correct (e.g., CUPS and the printer dialogs use "letter" as default page size and /etc/papersize contains the string "letter").

The problem does not happen with Evince and LibreOffice, so I imagine it is some issue with KDE.

I have tried installing a newer version of Okular via snap, but the problem persists.

Any ideas on how to set Okular's default page size to "letter"?

**Updates:**

- This problem seems like a regression of this bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=229261.  Regrettably, no solution was posted back then.
- Bug reports regarding this issue:

  - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtbase-opensource-src/+bug/1776173
  - https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=363326
- So, it seems is a problem with libqt5printsupport5 (see https://bugs.gentoo.org/617460).  Now the issue is how to update just this package in Ubuntu.

Comment: Does https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=982092&sid=91bb8f00a779da94bbfaf6b7b6110ac5#p982092 help?

Comment: @DKBose, no it didn't.  Okular's print dialog no longer has an "Advanced tab."

Comment: Just for reference: The second bug report says something is fixed in QT 5.11, but 18.04 has QT 5.9.

Comment: I have this issue as well on 18.04.1, but note that QT 5.11 appears to be installed:  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5.11

Comment: Ignore my previous comment.  18.04 does not use 5.11.

Comment: Great to know that this is a bug and not my stupidity.