# Ubuntu 18.04 Okular printing regression? Multiple pages per sheet with page border

Tags: kubuntu, printing, okular

In Ubuntu 16.04, Okular had this nice "Pages" tab in the printing dialog:
[image: Okular Printing Dialog in Ubuntu 16.04]

In Ubuntu 18.04, this tab is not there anymore. There is a similar option for printing multiple pages per sheet in the printer "Properties" dialog, but it doesn't allow printing a border around each page.
Is there a way to get this "Pages" tab also in Okular of Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I see what you see and it's possible that the lack of the feature is somehow related to the move to Qt5. Others have also experienced print-related issues for qt5 applications. See [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1678060#p1678060) and other posts in that thread.

Comment: This seems to be related to this other bug: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048311/cannot-change-okulars-default-page-size-under-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but FYI I solved the problem by printing with `evince`, which works fine in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems it's a QT5 "problem" (thanks DK Bose for the comment and link). So now I have four options (for printing 9 pages per side, with borders, duplex):

1. Print with Okular. Unfortunately I can't print borders around the pages.
2. Print manually with

   ```
   lp -d HP -o sides=two-sided-long-edge -o landscape -o number-up=9 -o page-border=single foo.pdf
   ```

   Unfortunately this doesn't print duplex, probably because of this [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1530244).
3. Downgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.
4. Print on Windows in my virtual machine :D I anyway already need Windows for upgrading my navigation device, copy photos from my phone and copy files to usb sticks fast.

Any other ideas? I really don't like any of those four options. This is basic printing, shouldn't be so hard.